# Tkinter Entry/Optionmenu combination

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a GUI whereby I pose three questions via tkinter. I am able to have the option for the user to write in the blank space; nevertheless I would like one of the three questions to be answered supported by an OptionMenu (essentially limiting the potential answer to a dropdown list which is in this case called OPTIONS). Namely, I'm talking ***self.var3*** as the widget section which should be providing dropdown options.
Code below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

players_list = []

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, title, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)  # initialize base class
        self.pack()
        self.master.title(title)

        OPTIONS = ["Ronaldo","Messi"] #etc

        self.var1 = StringVar()
        self.var2 = StringVar()
        
        variable = StringVar()
        variable.set(OPTIONS[0]) # default value
        w = OptionMenu(Tk(), variable, *OPTIONS)
        self.var3 = w

        Label(self, text="Player One: ").pack(side=LEFT)
        Entry(self, textvariable=self.var1).pack(side=LEFT)
        Label(self, text="Player Two: ").pack(side=LEFT)
        Entry(self, textvariable=self.var2).pack(side=LEFT)
        Label(self, text="Player Three: ").pack(side=LEFT)
        Entry(self, textvariable=self.var3).pack(side=LEFT) 

        Button(self, width=15, text="ENTER", command=self.enter).pack(side=LEFT)
        Button(self, width=15, text="PRINT", command=self.printIt).pack(side=LEFT)

    def enter(self):
        self.player1 = self.var1.get()
        self.player2 = self.var2.get()
        players_list.append(self.player1) #Adds choice to list
        players_list.append(self.player2) #Adds choice to list
        
    def printIt(self):
        print(self.player1)
        print(self.player2)

app = App("Player's Names")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: whats the problem here?

Comment: If your asking how to fetch the input you can use, `variable.get()`

Comment: @CoolCloud essentially I'd like to display an OptionMenu rather than an empty box next to the third question. I'm struggling to find a way to display that in the same widget since self.var3 does not seem to be storing the dropdown list

Comment: I think `self.var3` should be a `SringVar()` and not w and you havent used `w.pack()` ?

Comment: w.pack() creates the option but in another widget and not next to the question unfortunately

Comment: i think for that you have to use a precicse way of placing things like `.grid()`  or `.place()`